# Connecting to MySQL database across the sites

Tags: c#, mysql

I created a .exe file to ping the MySQL server database which is installed in my machine using C#. When I tried to access the MySQL server in my machine from different sites in India, its working fine for me. But when I tried sharing the same .exe file with my Stakeholders who are from Arizona, they failed doing the same. We all are connected through same internet connections but the domains are different across the sites. Please let me know if I need to change settings in MySQL in my machine. Please find the code snippet I used to create .exe file in C#. I'm using MySQL 5.2.6. Please help solving the issue. Thanks in advance.

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace ConsoleApplication1

{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string srevername = "Server=my machine ip; Database=data_base; Uid=user; Password=Password";
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(srevername);
            MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "update hon_count SET count = count+1 WHERE tool_name = 'export_points'";

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _failed_? Any exception or error message?

Comment: Hi Soner, the error message they got is "Unable to connect to any of the MySQL host". Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible issues.

- Try to ping your server IP
- if Ping is ok then try to check if firewall is allowed to open mysql
  port(3306).
- Try to connect with some tools which you are able to query (there [is free one](http://www.heidisql.com/) if you dont have)

Because "Unable to connect to any of the MySQL host" means that your app cant access to that server

Comment: Hello Volodymyr, I went to my machine's Windows Firewall's settings and observed that its not allowing the program named "MySQL56" to be accessed from Domain. So, I allowed it now. You think its enough or you want me to try some thing more. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Try to see :) sometimes its hard to guess until you try, as there can be some thing else